# Are browsers vulnerable to loading a web page via iframe hidden within <img> data?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, iframe

I want to place an iframe code inside a picture (png, jpg or gif) file. It is possible somehow?

I want to place this iframe code, which is loading a website in 0X0 pixel:

```
<iframe src="http://test.com" height="0" width="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
</iframe>
```

I was reading this article describing a new vulnerability:

http://threatpost.com/png-image-metadata-leading-to-iframe-injections/104047

So basically, I want a working example that one can load a website in 0X0 pixels when somebody visits this image url.

Comment: But at 0x0 pixels the user won't be able to see the web site, and it will just ping a server somewhere needlessly.  Or is there some other reason?

Comment: You can't embed the iframe element in the image itself. The code in the link you provided has the iframe data encoded in the bytes of an image. The javascript on the page then extracts the malicious iframe code from the image and loads it. This essentially makes the malicious code invisible from the page source.
EDIT: Also I hope you have no malicious intends with your question.

Comment: @dijive I thought it was in the picture metadata, which is usually harmless stuff like date, time, f-stop, shutter, geolocation, maybe author or title.  The idea being that perhaps there's some blog plugin for photos that never thought to taint-check that stuff and would give it passage to the browser's html.

Comment: @Paul I could be mistaken but it looks like the code calls the `getImageData()` function, which returns an array with color and alpha information for every pixel. It then loops over every 4 integers to read the data from every pixel and converts it to a character. Also I am not completely sure if javascript would have access to that sort of meta-data

Comment: Hmm, your'e right, that's image data, not metadata.  The teasers for the article mention metadata.  But then the decode relies on having that javascript code already in place, so the site has to be more or less hacked or malicious or using something hacked or malicious.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is **no** if you want create an img file that when loaded by an `<img>` HTML tag, inserts arbitrary Javascript or HTML code into a website without any other helper code running.

But the short answer is **yes**, you can create an img file to do those things if the website already has malicious or badly-behaving code that will decode the payload.

The report in the article is **not** very new **nor** threatening considering that any clickable `javascript:` link can contain similar string-encoded material.

The example in the article requires single-purpose Javascript helper code to already be loaded by the website.

I would like to copy the code here, but the link posted contains an image of code, not text,
and we should respect the copyright of their material.

Line 24 of that code fetches the raw data from the img, lines 28-31 decode a text payload from the img data via javascript assembling it as string `strData` which could contain an HTML iframe statement, and could have added it to the web page but in this code instead calls a callback with it (line 34) or alerts it (line 49) thus looking like more of a demo than an attack.

Things like this already exist though they are usually redirects to a spammer's web site.

Such payloads can be hidden in any long string and encoded and decoded by a variety of simple means.

Hiding a 0x0 iframe in a website sounds like a recipe for click-fraud of pay-per-click advertising schemes, not fraud of consumers directly.  When the iframe is loaded, most servers will show as referer the site it was embedded into and it looks similar to a link-click.